# How to add resources to firefox cache database manually?

Tags: firefox, https, browser-cache

My ISP blocks websites from time to time. Recently I cannot access `https` powered sites.
Firefox cannot load `https://ajax.googleapis.com/.../jquery.min.js` ...
But I can still access `http://ajax.googleapis.com/.../jquery.min.js` ...
I notice that: If I access the `https` resource,  firefox cannot load from `http-cached` files.
Is there some kind of tool/method to maniplate firefox caches.
I want to add `https://.../jquery.min.js` to firefox cache database manually.

---

#### UPDATE:

I use a foreign proxy to fix the problem. (Firefox+FoxyProxy)

Comment: A work around *maybe* greasemonkey

Comment: @DaveRook Some https requests are from another js files. Simply changing the `src` attribute of `<script>` tags is not enough.

Comment: I never said you would be changing the source attribute of script!

Comment: @DaveRook Thanks for your advice, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched over and found no ready-to-use library or add-on. Basically one can add or edit cache entries, by editing raw cache structure (_CACHE_MAP_, _CACHE_001_, ...), but this is not trivial.

These are useful link for parsing a cache directory:

- https://code.google.com/p/firefox-cache-forensics/wiki/FfFormat
- http://articles.forensicfocus.com/2012/03/09/firefox-cache-format-and-extraction/
- https://wiki.mozilla.org/Necko/Cache
- http://davidkoepi.wordpress.com/2010/11/27/firefoxforensics/
- http://people.mozilla.org/~chofmann/l10n/tree/mozilla/netwerk/cache/src/nsDiskCacheMap.cpp
- http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=637514

Answer (score -2):

You can completely disable cache with Web Developer extension - https://addons.mozilla.org/bg/firefox/addon/web-developer/
..or you can  download whole website for offline use - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook/

Comment: I also have thousands of unrelated answers...